# TextSearch engine in MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to create a search feature in my application using c# Driver for MongoDb.

When user search for a list of words I want to display first the exact match (if it exists) followed by the most interesting posts.

I've a text-index like this:

```
collection.CreateIndex(IndexKeys<Post>.Text(p => p.BodyPlainText));
```

I started this way:

```
var textSearchQueryExact = Query.Matches("BodyPlainText", searchString);
var textSearchQueryFullText = Query.Text(searchString);
var textSearchQuery = Query.Or(textSearchQueryFullText, textSearchQueryExact);
```

This generates the following query:

```
{  "$or" : [ { "$text" : { "$search" : "My example text" } }, { "BodyPlainText" : /My example text/ }] }
```

But it doesn't works! Zero results and, in MongoVUE, I recieve no explain. If I remove one of the two query filters it works, while with both doesn't.

I also find this restriction in Mongo documentation:

```
"To use a $text query in an $or expression, all clauses in the $or array must be indexed."
```

but the propery is the same and it is indexed.

What I miss?

Is this the right way to achieve the result I want?

**Update**

Using only textSearch query with this syntax:

```
{ "$text" : { "$search" : "il ricorrente lamentava che mentre" } }
```

give me the wrong result due to stem and stop word elaboration (I think):

[image]

Comment: Is there something I am missing here perhaps? Why would the `$text` search not return the most relevant ( exact match ) first without the use of an additional `$regex` operator statement? The syntax here suggests that you are using MongoDB 2.6 or greater, but I do not see usage of the `$meta` "textScore" in order to sort the relevance.

Comment: Stemming and stop words prevents to search for an exact match. If you want to search for an exact phrase you have to use a different text-search syntax (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/). 
TextScore is in my query but not in the example code; textScore is not my primary problem. Query and textScore sorting works perfectly with a single filter.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can do this pretty much exactly as the error message produced says that you should be processing this. This is actually part of how the "index intersection" works in MongoDB 2.6 and greater. It was "sort of" there for [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) influenced queries before, but there is a lot more "under the hood" now. So basically add an index like the error asks you to:

Considering the data:

```js
db.example.insert({ "text": "This is what I want" })
```

Then add the indexes:

```js
db.example.ensureIndex({ "text": "text" })
db.example.ensureIndex({ "text": 1 })
```

So then the query works as you would expect:

```js
db.example.find(
    { 
        "$or": [ 
            { "$text": { "$search": "This is what I want" } }, 
            { "text": /This is what I want/  }
        ]
    },
    { "score": { "$meta": "textScore" } }
).pretty()
```

Noting that I actually did add the [**`$meta`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/meta/) in there even if the `.sort()` was omitted. But pretty much where I was going from comments is that this is actually the same:

```js
db.example.find(
    { 
        "$or": [
            { "$text": { "$search": "This is what I want" } }
        ]
    },
    { "score": { "$meta": "textScore" } }
).pretty()
```

So while there is an effort to "intersect" in the first example, the document score for the exact match will remain the same:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53870b75015cb64be54d7ecf"),
    "text" : "This is what I want",
    "score" : 1
}
```

For more of a "stemming" example as you mentioned then there is this to consider:

```js
db.example.insert({ "text": "these colors are mine" })
db.example.insert({ "text": "This color are mine" })
```

And both of the query forms:

```js
db.example.find(
    { 
        "$or": [
            { "$text": { "$search": "This color are mine" } },
            { "text": /This color are mine/  }
        ]
    },
    { "score": { "$meta": "textScore" }}
).pretty()

db.example.find(
    { 
        "$or": [
            { "$text": { "$search": "This color are mine" } }
         ]
    },
    { "score": { "$meta": "textScore" }}
).pretty()
```

Superfluous use of [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) there in all cases, but It's quick to copy and paste. But again the report is the same value being returned:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53870f5a015cb64be54d7ed0"),
    "text" : "these colors are mine",
    "score" : 1.5
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5387114b015cb64be54d7ed1"),
    "text" : "This color are mine",
    "score" : 1.5
}
```

So that is pretty much how the rankings sort out when doing a query with that form.

Comment: So I need only to create an Ascending index for the property? I tryied this but creating the index for BodyPlainText property I recieve "Error creating index WriteConcern detected an error 'Btree::insert: key too large to index, failing..."

Comment: @danyolgiax I gave a minimal example of the use case, but what you are experiencing is a general limitation of a standard "Btree" index in that the index size breaks the current limits over a "large" text field for the key length. But the point I am making is the additional `$regex` search term here offers no real value when used with a "text" search as the "rankings" will be the same for the "exact" and "stemmed" match. Just how it works.

Comment: So it's impossible to create an index on a large text property... Do I have an alternative? My code is basically the same as your example.

Comment: @danyolgiax A large text field with a regular Btree index would break the length constraint, yes. But you are missing the point, which is you do not need the comparison that you are trying to achieve. I demonstrated in response to your **earliest** comment on the question to mine why this makes no difference to the order of results.

Comment: Ah! Ok now I've got it! I'm going to test it now and I'll give you a feedback.

Comment: @danyolgiax Looks like your text index contains multiple fields where the "title" of the post is weighted higher (note the word match there). Also your text search is currently for "all the words", you seem to want a [phrase](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases) match which would be "\"il ricorrente lamentava che mentre\""

Comment: The first highlighted text is not title but "Results for words: ....". 
Sure I need "phrase search" followed by "words search" that is the main discussion about to use an OR operator to search both. I think the answer in this case is "it's not possible".

Comment: @danyolgiax I'm not talking about the weighting and not referring to the section you highligted but the first result. See the word "ricorrente" in the title of that result but not in the body (excerpt). This indicates that weighting has been used and why the results have different scores. All things being equal, things work exactly as I have described them. But if you weight one field over the other then you will get the results that you are showing.

Comment: No weight has been set, the index has been created like this: db.Posts.ensureIndex({BodyPlainText: "text",Subject: "text"})

Answer (score 1):

try set default language in index

```
db.CollectionName.ensureIndex(
   { BodyPlainText: "text" },
   { default_language: "it" }
)
```

and in query

```
{ $text: { $search: "il ricorrente lamentava che mentre", $language: "it" } }
```

and stemming will help you, not disturb